# Suse11 - How to use external DVD ROM

Tags: opensuse

I am going to install a external DVD ROM to my server, it use USB to connect to the server. I want to ask how to configure my server to detect and use the external server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new device should be detected just fine without intervention. It was working as far back as SLES10 and OpenSUSE 10.2 on a server with USB1 ports, so the 11.x variants should work even better.